# Longest opening variation that you can memorize?

Tags: opening

What is the longest opening line or variation, starting from the first move, that you memorized?

Answer (score 2):

As black Sicilian Dragon 
1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6
5. Nc3 g6
I don’t care to do more since at that point many variations can diverge heavily, but I expect 6. Be3 Before fianchettoing my bishop.

As white Ruy Lopez, Rio Gambit line
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 Nf6 4. O-O Nxe4
5. Re1 Nd6 6. Nxe5 Nxe5 7. Rxe5+ Be7 8. Bf1
This is just a fun one

And generally since there wasn’t any obvious objective a few things to add if you were looking for data or a suggestion (even though there is a high chance you out rank me)

• English Opening and King’s Indian are very powerful opening I plan on studying due to the success of AlphaZero

•Learning gambits are great for improving your ability to calculate attacks and general aggressive intuition

•My favorite way to practice openings is with friends or against Stockfish ai on Arena chess since you get similar variations, particularly I’ve found ~2200 range to be great for popular Sicilian lines

•Mainstream opening traps aren’t worth it to study (unless to avoid) since those situations are so well known they are often avoided, some obscure ones like when Bobby Fischer coined his famed opening trap

---

I believe it’s better to study opening theory as opposed to specific lines since it provides a stronger, flexible ideology for how to open, and with thousands of games it’s fairly common to remember them anyways

Comment: This question is just a curiosity of course, I am not implying that memorizing is better than understanding.

Comment: I expected so, just some extra info